# Calculate row means on subset of columns selected via external rank

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame containing a set of item ratings generated by multiple coders. Not all coders ranked all items. For each item, I would like to generate an average based on ratings from the top two coders, as indicated by an external ranking system. Coders are ranked from A (highest) to D (lowest). In my current code, I order columns by coder ranking (from A to D), then use a for loop:

```
   CoderA CoderB CoderC CoderD
1       2      1     NA      1
2       1      3      3     NA
3      NA     NA      4      5
4       7      6      7      6
5       3      3      4      2
6       2      2     NA     NA
7       2     NA      2      1
8       5      3     NA      4
9       7      7      6     NA
10      1     NA      3      4

df <- data.frame(
CoderA = c(2,1,NA,7,3,2,2,5,7,1),
CoderB = c(1,3,NA,6,3,2,NA,3,7,NA),
CoderC = c(NA,3,4,7,4,NA,2,NA,6,3),
CoderD = c(1,NA,5,6,2,NA,1,4,NA,4))

df$first_sc <- apply(df, 1, function(x) names(df[which(!is.na(x))])[1])
df$sec_sc <- apply(df, 1, function(x) names(df[which(!is.na(x))])[2])

for (x in seq(1,nrow(df))) {
  first_rating <- df[x,df$first_sc[x]]
  second_rating <- df[x,df$sec_sc[x]]
  df$BestAvg[x] <- (first_rating + second_rating) / 2
  }
```

**Question 1:** Any suggestions for a more parsimonious solution to the simple case above? (The for loop isn't preferred, but I'm stuck on the indexing in similar apply functions.)

**Question 2:** In a second dataframe, columns are **not** ordered by coder ranking (e.g., columns are ordered 'CoderD', 'CoderB', 'CoderC', 'CoderA'). How might I approach the same problem given this constraint?

Comment: For the 1st question, you could do `apply(df,1,function(x) mean(x[!is.na(x)][1:2]))`. Not sure I understand the 2nd question, couldn't you reorder the columns beforehand?

Comment: Your suggestion is a nice solution for Question 1; thanks! Question 2 applies to a more dynamic case. In my full script, external rankings of coders are adjusted based on other data, and can change from one portion of the script to another. I don't want to reorder columns each time the rankings change, thus the quest for an alternative where column rankings can be specified directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question,
you could get the mean of the first 2 non NA values per row using `apply`:

```
df$BestAvg = apply(df,1,function(x) mean(x[!is.na(x)][1:2]))
```

In the case that the ranking of coders is actually `CoderD > CoderB > CoderC > CoderA`:

```
r = c("CoderD", "CoderB", "CoderC", "CoderA")
df$BestAvg2 = apply(df,1,function(x) mean(x[r][!is.na(x[r])][1:2]))
```

This returns:

```
     CoderA CoderB CoderC CoderD BestAvg BestAvg2
1       2      1     NA      1     1.5      1.0
2       1      3      3     NA     2.0      3.0
3      NA     NA      4      5     4.5      4.5
4       7      6      7      6     6.5      6.0
5       3      3      4      2     3.0      2.5
6       2      2     NA     NA     2.0      2.0
7       2     NA      2      1     2.0      1.5
8       5      3     NA      4     4.0      3.5
9       7      7      6     NA     7.0      6.5
10      1     NA      3      4     2.0      3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`...

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(case=1:n()) %>% #add case numbers
              gather(key=coder,value=score,-case) %>% #convert to long format
              filter(!is.na(score)) %>% #remove NA scores
              arrange(case,coder) %>% #order by case and coder
              group_by(case) %>% #group by case
              summarise(bestavg=mean(head(score,2))) %>% #mean of top two
              right_join(df %>% mutate(case=1:n())) #merge with original data

df2
# A tibble: 10 x 6
    case   bestavg CoderA CoderB CoderC CoderD
   <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1       1.5      2      1     NA      1
 2     2       2.0      1      3      3     NA
 3     3       4.5     NA     NA      4      5
 4     4       6.5      7      6      7      6
 5     5       3.0      3      3      4      2
 6     6       2.0      2      2     NA     NA
 7     7       2.0      2     NA      2      1
 8     8       4.0      5      3     NA      4
 9     9       7.0      7      7      6     NA
10    10       2.0      1     NA      3      4
```

This will work provided your coder names sort into the preference order you want (as you describe).  The order of the columns in the dataframe is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! This works well. To ensure coder names sort correctly when columns are out of order, I added a line before the arrange statement that converts coder to a factor and specifies the correct level order:   `mutate(coder =  factor(coder, levels = c('CoderA', 'CoderB', 'CoderC', 'CoderD'))) %>%`